# Problems while transforming into a pandas dataframe the following xml elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am using beautiful soup for parsing and extracting some info from a bunch of xml files as follows:

```
import os
a_lis = []
for filepath in glob(os.path.join('../data/trainingFiles/', '*.xml')):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        content = f.read()
        results = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
        #print(results)
        for LabelInteractions in results.find_all("labelinteractions"):
            #print(LabelInteractions)
            for labelinteractions in LabelInteractions.findAll('labelinteraction'):
                print(labelinteractions)
```

out:

```
<labelinteraction precipitant="ritonavir" precipitantcode="N0000007423" type="Unspecified interaction"></labelinteraction>
<labelinteraction precipitant="gc stimulator" precipitantcode="NO MAP" type="Unspecified interaction"></labelinteraction>
....
<labelinteraction precipitant="riociguat" precipitantcode="N0000188995" type="Unspecified interaction"></labelinteraction>
<labelinteraction effect=" 25064002: Headache (finding)" precipitant="alcohol" precipitantcode="N0000007432" type="Pharmacodynamic interaction"></labelinteraction>
```

How can I transform those xml attributes into a pandas dataframe format?, the columns would look something like this:

```
precipitant  precipitantcode type effect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store columns in arrays and then create data frame:

```
from collections import defaultdict

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<labelinteraction precipitant="ritonavir" precipitantcode="N0000007423" type="Unspecified interaction"></labelinteraction>
<labelinteraction precipitant="gc stimulator" precipitantcode="NO MAP" type="Unspecified interaction"></labelinteraction>
<LabelInteraction type="Pharmacodynamic interaction" precipitant="alcohol" precipitantCode="N0000007432" effect=" 25064002: Headache (finding)"/>
""") 

columns = ['precipitant', 'precipitantcode', 'type', 'effect']
d = defaultdict(list)

for labelinteraction in soup.findAll('labelinteraction'):
    for col in columns:
        d[col].append(labelinteraction[col] if labelinteraction.has_attr(col) else None)

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Output:

```
     precipitant precipitantcode                         type                         effect
0      ritonavir     N0000007423      Unspecified interaction                           None
1  gc stimulator          NO MAP      Unspecified interaction                           None
2        alcohol     N0000007432  Pharmacodynamic interaction   25064002: Headache (finding)
```

Comment: yes I actually tried to define the lists and merge everything in the pandas dataframe.. however I thought it was a more pythonic way of doing it... thanks!

Comment: I found one Issue... I realize that there are some elements that have an `effect` parameter. For example: `<LabelInteraction type="Pharmacodynamic interaction" precipitant="alcohol" precipitantCode="N0000007432" effect=" 25064002: Headache (finding)"/>` Is there any way of put `NaN`if the element doesnt have any effect attribute?

Comment: Thanks... actually I just realized that because of that I thought that using the lists was wrong... because when I tried to get the `effect` value the BS did not find it for some cases...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of columns you want:

```
cols = ['precipitant', 'precipitantcode', 'type']
```

Then you can iterate over them and append to an array in a dictionary:

```
d = {}
for labelinteractions in LabelInteractions.findAll('labelinteraction'):
    for c in cols:
        if not c in d:
            d[c] = [labelinteractions[c]]
        else:
            d[c].append(labelinteractions[c])
```

When finished, you can request the DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

This is what I get for your sample:

```
     precipitant precipitantcode                         type
0      ritonavir     N0000007423      Unspecified interaction
1  gc stimulator          NO MAP      Unspecified interaction
2      riociguat     N0000188995      Unspecified interaction
3        alcohol     N0000007432  Pharmacodynamic interaction
```